# Unable to see newly created csv file

Tags: python, csv

I created 2 button. The first button allow me to write 1234 in AgmPlot csv format. But i am unable to see the newly created csv file in AgmFolder - I have to re run the program again to see the newly created Excel csv file.

```
def AGM():
    Plot()
    newDirRH = "C:/AgmPlots"
    newfile = newDirRH + "/TabulatedStats.csv"
    text_file = open(newfile, "w")
    stringText = "1234"
    x= stringText
    text_file.write(x)
    text_file.close()
    print "Done"

def AGMFolder():
    webbrowser.open(r'C:\AgmPlots')

def Plot():
    py.plot(10,20)
    py.show()
```

Problem is due to the Plot(). I dont wish to take it away but how can i fix this problem??

```
if __name__ == '__main__': #start of program
    master = Tk.Tk() 
    button = Tk.Button(text='AGM', command=AGM, fg="red") 
    button.config( height = 10, width = 40 )
    button.pack() #pack is needed to display the button
    button1 = Tk.Button(text='Open AGM Folder', command = AGMFolder, fg="red")
    button1.config( height = 10, width = 40 )
    button1.pack()
    master.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is `py` in `Plot()`? You don't have the complete code, thus makes it hard for us to help. I have tried the `AGM()` code and it works, so the problem is due to `Plot()` like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `py` in `Plot()` refers to `matplotlib.pyplot`?

In that case, your call to `py.show()` will block until the plot window is closed; change it to `py.show(block=False)` and re-read the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show).